# How can I test if a background job failed before it exits?

Tags: shell-script, background-process, x

I'm writing a script that launches a virtual framebuffer with Xvfb. I want to make sure the command succeeds, but I don't want the script to wait until the command completes, because Xvfb continues running until the X server is killed. For example:

```
if ! Xvfb $DISPLAY &; then
    echo 'Error: failed to create virtual frame buffer'
    exit 1
fi

xpid=$!

# do stuff that uses frame buffer

kill $xpid
```

The problem with this is it throws a syntax error on `&;`:

```
$ stuff.sh 
stuff.sh: line 149: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
stuff.sh: line 149: `if ! Xvfb $DISPLAY &; then'
```

I tried changing that line to `if ! Xvfb $DISPLAY & ;` but it still throws the error.

Comment: try removing `;` and shift `then` to next line.

Comment: Why not `xvfb-run`? It would run the commands that need the server only after the server successfully started. It would be safer than waiting some guessed amount of time.

Comment: @JoL I didn't know about it, but that's what I was looking for initially. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `&` symbol is a `control operator` and ends the list of commands to be tested. Following that definition, the following is free of *syntax* errors:

```
if ! Xvfb $DISPLAY & then
    echo 'Error: failed to create virtual frame buffer'
    exit 1
fi
```

The trouble is, by backgrounding the `Xvfb` command, the test result will *always* be zero/true.

I would start the process, then wait long enough for it to die, then check to see if it is still around:

```
Xvfb $DISPLAY &
xvfbpid=$!
sleep 3 ## adjust to taste
if ! ps -p $xvfbpid > /dev/null
then
  echo 'Error: failed to create virtual frame buffer'
  exit 1
fi
```

References:

- [Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/): Shell & Utilities - Shell Command Language - Shell Commands - Lists - Asynchronous Lists - Exit Status

Comment: Using `kill -0 "$xvfbpid"` would also test whether the given PID was alive.

Comment: There's a theoretical risk that the process could end and a new process re-use that pid before the test.  It's really never going to happen in just three seconds, but it's worth mentioning for when folk transfer this to situations of much longer duration.